# MmProbeAndLockPages() failed while coding windows driver

Tags: windows, kernel, driver

I am coding a windows driver.

I try to probes a Virtual Memory Page using **MmProbeAndLockPages()** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-mmprobeandlockpages

First I allocate the MDL using  **IoAllocateMdl()**. Then I probes the virtual memory page. The code is like :

```
PMDL pMdl = IoAllocateMdl(Dest, (ULONG)Size, FALSE, FALSE, NULL);
if (pMdl) {
    __try {
        MmProbeAndLockPages(pMdl, KernelMode, IoModifyAccess);
        MmUnlockPages(pMdl);
    }
    __except (EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER) {
        status = GetExceptionCode();
    }
    IoFreeMdl(pMdl);
}
```

I also tried to attach to the process using **KeStackAttachProcess()** but it has no effect.

The **Dest** variable is a PVOID to a **userland** process' address. The address is valid because I can read from it.

Do you have an idea why **MmProbeAndLockPages()** failed and my code goes into the **except** branch?

The exception code is **0xC0000005** (which is an access violation) but I specified **IoModifyAccess/IoWriteAccess** and I should be able to write to a userland process from kernelland, right?

Even when I unset the WP bit of cr0, it doesn't work ... hum something weird is happening

I am using a windows 10.0.19044

Thanks

regards

Answer (score 0):

I have to change `IoModifyAccess` to `IoReadAccess`.

Then to call `MmProtectMdlSystemAddress()` with `PAGE_READWRITE`.